# WebViewClient.onPageCommitVisible() fired even for connection timeout

Tags: android, webview, webviewclient

I need to detect when a webpage load is completed in an Android WebView.

I tried to use WebViewClient.onPageCommitVisible() but it seems it is fired even when the connection to webpage fails for timeout.
What I'm missing?  Is there any safe wait to understand if the URL is fully loaded?